# CGAL/BGL Sample Code for Dijkstra Shortest Path on a Delaunay Triangulation creates Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, boost, cgal

I am currently working on solving a problem, where I need to get the shortest path on a delaunay triangulation.

In the CGAL documentation there is a sample code to exactly do this (Example 5.2):
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html

Unfortunately, I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to call this line

```
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(ft, source, distance_map(distance_pmap).predecessor_map(predecessor_pmap));
```

I did some testing and found out, that this is only happening if the point passed to the dijkstra_shortest_path function, as the "source" parameter, is having the coordinates [0,0].
The test case, which is causing the error is quite simple:

> [0,0]
>  [1,0]

Does anyone know how to fix it or what is calling the segmentation fault in the dijkstra_shortest_path function?

Comment: I just tried the examples `examples/BGL_triangulation_2/dijsktra.cpp` and  `examples/BGL_triangulation_2/dijkstra_with_internal_properties.cpp`. Both run fine using (0,0) as source. It would help if you provide a complete minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: Instead of their while loop to read the inputs I have this:
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            Point p;
            std::cin >> p;
            t.insert(p);
}

And my input file looks like this: 
0 0
1 0

Comment: if you have only 2 points, then the triangulation is not of dimension 2 and the wrapper might then have a bug. You should open an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues). As a workaround, you can call `t.dimension()` and workaround cases !=2 while CGAL team releases a proper patch.